# Trying to create 2 subfolders in the layour folder - Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create 2 subfolders in the layout folder. I have multiple layouts and it's hard to look through all of them until I find what I'm looking for. 
I tried this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile '/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['/src/main/java','.apt_generated']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['/src/main/aidl','.apt_generated']
        assets.srcDirs = ['/src/main/assets']
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        '/src/main/res/layouts/listandpager',
                        '/src/main/res/activity',
                        '/src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}
```

as this guy says here https://github.com/eskimoapps/ResourceNestingExample. But I think I'm doing something wrong because I still don't see them there.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio automatically sorts different version of the same file, so that they don't get displayed, for simplicity reasons. To show all present folders, choose the "Project" option from the drop-down menu that is located above the folders.

Comment: If you were to download the project, you could see that even on "Android" view you can still see two layout subfolders. I'm trying to do something like that. And even if I change as you said I still can't see them.